# Fill in missing rows with zeros

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get ratings, for a particular item in my database. Not all items have a rating for 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5; when that happens, how can I fill in the row with `0`'s?

So, for example when I have ratings for 1,2,3 but not for 4 and 5, how could I fill in those two rows with `0`'s?

```
select 
rating,
count(rating) as rating_count,
(count(rating) / (select count(item_id) from ratings where item_id = 3) * 100) as percent,
avg(rating)
from ratings 
where item_id = 3
group by rating desc
with rollup
```

Here is the above result for the above query, as you can see there is no 1 and 2 rating, how can I get those where `rating_count`, `percent` and `avg(rating)` are zeros?

[image: Results]

@Hogan's answer:

[image]

Comment: Do you need this for only one item or for all items?

Comment: I need this for one item, like when you view an app on the google play store, it has the number of people who rated 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn - couldn't get it to work on mysql rollup seems to mess with the standard way to do this.

Comment: @Hogan You were so close! I think I got it! Instead of placing the `item_id = 3` in the where you put it in the left join with an `and` after the two columns

Comment: yeah I tried `coalesce(item_id,3) =3` in the where -- that does not work because of the rollup.

Comment: what needs to happen is have your query as written and then join that to the missing rows.

Comment: @Hogan I added an answer based on your answer

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have got working (based on @Hogan's original query):

```
select
r_list.r as rating,
ifnull(count(rating), 0) as rating_count,
ifnull((count(rating) / (select count(item_id) from ratings where item_id = ?) * 100), 0) as percent,
ifnull(avg(rating), 0)
from (SELECT 1 AS r
UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS r
UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 AS r
UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 AS r
UNION ALL
    SELECT 5 AS r
) r_list
left join ratings on r_list.r = ratings.rating and item_id = ?
group by r_list.r desc
with rollup
```

Answer (score -1):

You will use someting along the lines of this to replace the null values as a 0:

```
SELECT ISNULL(rating, 0 ) FROM myTable
```

Comment: I think he wants to see rows for ratings he does not have -- not set a null rating to 0